# Bullet Physics and Iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bulletphysics

I'm trying to integrate physics bullet and OpenGL ES in iOS and it's working when I run on an Iphone 5. But when I try to use it with the Iphone 6 Simulator it fails. I'm getting the following warning saying that it's ignoring the bullet's files.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/alcampelo/Documents/Dice/bullet-2.82-r2704/lib/libBulletCollision_xcode4.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/alcampelo/Documents/Dice/bullet-2.82-r2704/lib/libBulletCollision_xcode4.aignoring file /Users/alcampelo/Documents/Dice/bullet-2.82-r2704/lib/libBulletDynamics_xcode4.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/alcampelo/Documents/Dice/bullet-2.82-r2704/lib/libBulletDynamics_xcode4.ald: warning:

Does anyone know what could be the problem? I already tried to add the arm64 architecture in Build Settings with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered how to do it! I was adding the arm64 architecture in Build Setting's Valid Architectures only for my project. It's also needed to do this configuration for the BulletCollision.xcodeproj, BulletDynamics.xcodeproj and LinearMath.xcodeproj.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply that the bullet library has not been built for the iOS Simulator (`x86_64` in this case).

You will need to build it for that architecture in order to run your app on the simulator (this is non-trivial).

You might also consider using a framework like [GamePlay3d](http://gameplay3d.org) which uses Bullet and comes with pre-compiled binaries (I cannot vouch for which architectures are supported at the moment, however).